# Multi-measure percent repeats in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, repeats

I'm trying to copy a score that indicates the repeat of a 4-bar phrase that has the 4 repeat bars laid out on the sheet, with a single (4-slash) percent-repeat symbol symbol in the middle, sort of like this:

```
   | music | music | music | music |

                   4
   |       |       %       |       |
```

The [snippets](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/snippets/repeats) don't help me with this.

Note: I'm using ver. 2.14, so it might just be that my version is somewhat old.

Comment: The third image in http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.15/Documentation/notation/short-repeats#percent-repeats shows percent repeat signs that are good for several bars. Is that not what you want?

Comment: No, I've only seen percent's applied to chunks <=2 measures; I want lilypond to recognize that I have a 4-bar phrase, and lay-out the 4-bars, with an appropriate repeat symbol (but not fill in the music)

Comment: @Dave - perhaps posting an image of the excerpt from the score you are trying to copy will help clarify exactly what you are asking. Frr me personally, I am thinking of a few different possibilities concerning what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe adapting the ["Isolated percent repeats" snippet](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.14/Documentation/snippets/repeats#isolated-percent-repeats.ly) may help: just replace the whole note by a `longa`:

```
    makePercent =
    #(define-music-function (parser location note) (ly:music?)
       "Make a percent repeat the same length as NOTE."
       (make-music 'PercentEvent
                   'length (ly:music-length note)))

    \relative c'' {
      c1 | d1 | c1 | b1 \break
      \makePercent s\longa \break
      c1 | c4 d4 b4 f4 | a1 a1 \bar "|."
    }
```

will result in:

[image: Lilypond output]